# Parsing HTML with formatted text

Tags: php, html, parsing, domdocument

I'm parsing an HTML web page with DOMDocument.

Here is my code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$input = file_get_contents($url); //Url passato come parametro
$doc->loadHTML( $input );
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$article = $xpath->query('//div[@class="entry-container fix"]');
```

In $article I have all text inside a "entry-container fix" Div.

But this text in the web page have a formatted text.
Simply expample:

```
<div> 
   <p> Text <strong> Strong text </strong> </p>
</div>
```

With my code, I lost all bold, italian characters, all paragraphs ecc...
There's a way to get all formatted text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065063/how-to-keep-html-formatting-intact-when-parsing-with-dom-no-tag-stripping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the saveHTML function to extract that HTML (here is the link : http://php.net/manual/fr/domdocument.savehtml.php). It would look something like this :

```
$sFormated = $doc->saveHTML($article->item(0));
```

Comment: I'm trying to use it. But it doesn't work. Can you explane me better how use it with in my code? 
I've tried for example : 

$doc->saveHTML($article['output']->nodeValue(0));

But still not work.